# Gridview herdando propriedades

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, gridview

Em todas as minhas grid´s eu tenho que definir muitas propriedades, gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de definir as propriedades somente em um vez em um único lugar.

Exemplo de grid:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você fala assim, são propriedades padrões em todo o seu grid? se sim me coloque algum exemplo!

Comment: Olá Maria, desculpe se não fui claro... o que quis dizer é que em todas as grid´s do meu projeto, eu defino as propriedades "GridLines", "CellPadding","PagerSettings" e outras mais. Eu gostaria de definir isso somente uma vez para todas as grids, dessa forma quando precisar alterar algo não tenho que em cada uma e alterar... fui claro?

Comment: Douglas Cristhian, foi sim!

Comment: Fiz um exemplo @DouglasCristhian que você pode usar, inclusive pode ter até dois ou mais métodos extensivos gerando assim mais tipos de GridView, vê se para você é isso.

Comment: Já deu uma estudada em user controls? Poderá ter ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1 - Criando um classe `library` para herdar da classe `GridView` e colocar por padrão as suas configurações**

Crie um projeto class library e coloque esse código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Default.WebControl
{
    [ControlValuePropertyAttribute("SelectedValue")]
    [ToolboxData("GridViewDefault")]
    public class GridViewDefault : GridView
    {
        public GridViewDefault()
        {
            this.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
            this.CellPadding = 5;
            this.CellSpacing = 6;
            this.Width = new Unit("100%");
        }
    }
}
```

Após essa criação da classe library faça a referencia no seu projeto Web pelo menu `Add Reference`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Indicando ai a sua `class library`. Agora configure no seu projeto a diretiva da seguinte forma:

```
<%@ Register Namespace="Default.WebControl" Assembly="Default.WebControl" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

E logo pode se utilizar normalmente o novo GridView criado perceba:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código completo **Aspx**:

```
<%@ Page Title="About" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplicationForms.About" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Register Namespace="Default.WebControl" Assembly="Default.WebControl" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: Title %>.</h2>
    <h3>Your application description page.</h3>
    <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
    <asp:GridViewDefault ID="GridViewDefault1" runat="server"></asp:GridViewDefault>       
    <asp:Button ID="BtnAtualizar" OnClick="BtnAtualizar_Click" runat="server"  />
</asp:Content>
```

---

Com método extensivo você consegue inclusive montar diversas configurações e fazer uma chamada no Load da Página.

**2 - Crie um classe com modificador `static` com um método também com modificador `static` dessa maneira:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
namespace System.Web.UI.WebControls
{
    public static class Methods
    {
        public static void RenderConfiguration(this GridView grid)
        {
            grid.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
            grid.CellPadding = 5;
            grid.CellSpacing = 6;
            grid.Width = new Unit("100%");
        }
    }
}
```

Obs: Siga esse exemplo de código só mudando a parte da configuração interna mediante as suas próprias configurações.

**No Load:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
namespace WebApplicationForms
{
    public partial class About : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GridView1.RenderConfiguration(); // chamando configuração padrão!
                GridView1.DataSource = new object[]{
                    new {Id = 1, Nome = "GridView 1"},
                    new {Id = 2, Nome = "GridView 2"},
                    new {Id = 3, Nome = "GridView 3"},
                    new {Id = 4, Nome = "GridView 4"},
                    new {Id = 5, Nome = "GridView 5"}
                };
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**3 - Pode-se também utilizar um método `static` por referencia, assim:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
namespace System.Web.UI.WebControls
{
    public static class Methods
    {        
        public static void RenderConfiguration(ref GridView grid)
        {
            grid.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
            grid.CellPadding = 5;
            grid.CellSpacing = 6;
            grid.Width = new Unit("100%");
        }
    }
}
```

**No Load:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
namespace WebApplicationForms
{
    public partial class About : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {                
                Methods.RenderConfiguration(ref GridView1); // chamando por referencia
                GridView1.DataSource = new object[]{
                    new {Id = 1, Nome = "GridView 1"},
                    new {Id = 2, Nome = "GridView 2"},
                    new {Id = 3, Nome = "GridView 3"},
                    new {Id = 4, Nome = "GridView 4"},
                    new {Id = 5, Nome = "GridView 5"}
                };
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ótimo @Maria! Parabéns!!! Fiz através do componente...